# When defining vertexes for shapes in object-space using Opengl does it matter what the range of x,y and z are

Tags: opengl, graphics

Am I correct in thinking that you would ultimately account for differences in coordinate systems in the model view matrix (via scaling).

most examples I have seen describe all of the original coordinates between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it doesn't matter. For example minecraft models have the unit length be the length of a block and most mobs are larger than then that. Also Kerbal Space program models have the unit length be roughly the height of a kerbal but all the rocket parts are much larger.

Once you position and get some perspective it doesn't matter what the original coordinate system was. It does make it easier to have different size models that share their unit length so you don't need to mess with scale matrices.